# Loading a file immediately upon launching the wolframscript REPL

Tags: scripting

When running, i.e., a bash shell, usually a file is automatically imported upon launch for convenience (`~/.bashrc`).

Can one do something similar when launching `wolframscript` (say: loading `~/wolfram.wls`?

Comment: [init.m](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html)?

Comment: @Roman: That answered the question. Thanks.